# Routing different youtube videos sound to different outputs

Tags: javascript, flash, youtube-api, browser-plugin

I'm not quite sure if this is possible but here is what I want to do:

I want to have 2 different youtube videos (instantiated using the js api) on a page and I want to route the sound from one of them to the regular speakers and the sound from the other one to the headphones.

I'm pretty much open to any possible solutions and any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is internal to the player itself. You don't have access to it.

Comment: So if I wrote my own flash player I'd have access to it? Given I'd have to host the videos myself?